# Can't retrieve Angularjs $scope array last object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have an array with object in $scope in angularjs. I successfully push the object into array. It shows array is form in console but I can't retrieve the last object of array like normal array in javascript. The following is my code.

```
$scope.messages = [];

$http.get("http://localhost/php/retrieve_message.php").success(function (data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.messages.push(data[i]);
        console.log("success");
    }
}).error(function ()
{
    console.log("error");
});
console.log([$scope.messages); console.log($scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1]);
```

Comment: `$http` is an async method. If you `console.log` out of them, it's return empty or undefined.

Comment: but I console with console.log($scope.messages); it display a list of object. The problem now is I want to get last object in $scope.messages array

Comment: It's is like @Davide said - the method is async, which means you cannot console.log it outside the get method and suspect that it has already finished pulling data from the server at that point.

Comment: Yeah as David said $http is async which means it will fire the http request and go ahead with executing the rest of the code. Once the response is received execution will come to the success/failure function.

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik thanks. Learn new thing today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.

```
$scope.messages = [];

$http.get("http://localhost/php/retrieve_message.php").success(function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.messages.push(data[i]);
        console.log("success");
    }
    console.log($scope.messages);
    console.log($scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1]);
}).error(function() {
    console.log("error");

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Problem Solved

Comment: @chanyoonghon Accept my answer  so.

Comment: But if I want to use the array in other place after $http. Can I do that?

Comment: @chanyoonghon you can use your array into `success` or you can think about https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

You are making an `Asynchronous request`.

> In this case, you receive a callback when the data has been received,
>   which lets the browser continue to work as normal while your request
>   is being handled.

```
 $scope.messages = [];

  $http.get("http://localhost/php/retrieve_message.php").success(function(data){
       for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            $scope.messages.push(data[i]);
             console.log("success");
       }
    // put your code in success method
    console.log($scope.messages);
    console.log($scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1]);

    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

In your case you are accessing the list `before the data has been received`.
So the length of $scope.messages is `0` and you are trying to get `$scope.messages[-1]`

> You can learn more about Synchronous and asynchronous requests
>   [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.messages = [];

  $http.get("http://localhost/php/retrieve_message.php").success(function(data){
       // this callback function gets executed only after server returns a successful response. So, here you have access to data you have got from the server.
       for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            $scope.messages.push(data[i]);
             console.log("success");
       }
       console.log([$scope.messages);
       console.log($scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1]);
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
    // Following code executes before even server returns data.
    //console.log([$scope.messages);
    //console.log($scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try by updating your for loop as :

```
for(var x in data){
    $scope.messages.push(x);
    console.log("success");
}
```